# Put chapter title in the middle of a page (vertically)

Tags: vertical-alignment, chapters, fncychap

I'm using `fncychap` package to customize my chapters' titles. I want to put the chapter title in the center of a separate page (vertically).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Bjornstrup}%how to put it in the center of the page
\newpage
somecontent....
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the macro `\chaptervc` to start your chapters. As you can see, it takes only one argument, just like the regular `\chapter` command.

It works by putting the original `\chapter` command output at vertical center, by using two `\vfill`s, one before, one after. Then it uses a `\clearpage` to get a new page, since you wanted to have your chapter title in an independent page. (Though a `\newpage` should also be good here, since it is very unlikely to remain any unprocessed floats at this point.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\long\def\chaptervc#1{\vfill\chapter{#1}\vfill\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\chaptervc{Bjornstrup}%how to put it in the center of the page

\lipsum[1]

\chaptervc{Another Chapter}

\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]

\chaptervc{And Another}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding `\vfill` before and after `\chapter{#1}` seems to do nothing to move the chapter heading down to the middle of the page. MMA's answer looks the same with or without them. The problem is that `\chapter` issues a `\clearpage` and the first `\vfill` ends up at the bottom of the previous page. Also, defining `\chaptervc` without an optional argument and without a star form limits its use.

One has to get inside the `\chapter` command's definition and put something before and after the start of the chapter heading. In the `fncychap` package, the chapter heading is started by the `\DOCH` command and finished off by either `\DOTI` or `\DOTIS`. In the following, I add `\vfil` vertical space before `\DOCH` and a `\clearpage` after `\DOTI` and `\DOTIS`. Also added are negative spaces cancel the positive space added elsewhere. No `\vfil` is placed after `\DOTI` because there is a `\vfil` contained inside `\clearpage`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% internal changes to chapter headings:
\let\oldDOCH\DOCH
\let\oldDOTI\DOTI
\let\oldDOTIS\DOTIS
\renewcommand\DOCH{\vspace{-50pt}\vfil\oldDOCH}
\renewcommand\DOTI [1]{\oldDOTI {#1}\vspace{-40pt}\clearpage}
\renewcommand\DOTIS[1]{\oldDOTIS{#1}\vspace{-40pt}\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Bjornstrup}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Another Chapter}

\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]

\chapter{And Another}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```